# Converting Excel's LINEST to C# - Specifically the Standard Error of Slope

Tags: c#, excel, math.net

I am working on converting the LINEST function in Excel to C#. I am having a hard time calculating the standard error of the slope.

The function I am working on converting is the following:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(known_ys,known_xs,TRUE,TRUE),2,1)
```

I am trying to use Math.Net's Numeric's library but am unable to get the standard error of the slope - only the R2'd.

If this question is too vague please let me know and I'll do my best to add more detail.

Appreciate any and all help.